# Gitlab can't open Directory

Tags: git, gitlab

I have to subprojects in my gitlab repository, client and server, but I can't open the server directory, what does the symbol in the screenshot mean? I suppose it means it is a seperate git repository, but I checked the server directory and there was no `.git` directory in it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This folder is a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). If you have committed and pushed the `.gitmodules` file, it should point to the specified repository in this file, for instance :

```
[submodule "server"]
    path = server
    url = git@github.com:username/somerepo.git
```

Note that if when you click on the folder and it doesn't redirect to the remote repository, it could mean :

- the external repo hasn't been added as a submodule (`git submodule`) but has been cloned into your repo (`git clone`)
- you haven't committed/pushed the `.gitmodules` file but you did push the submodule
- you have deleted the submodule locally but you didn't remove it from your remote so the it's still present on Gitlab

If you want to remove this submodule check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule)

Comment: I remember, server was a seperate project once and then i moved it into the main project, i think i might have commited servers .git folder, but then deleted the servers .git folder. The only .git related folder i still have is /.git (I never used submodules explicitly) can I do some sort of "cleanup" to remove the information from the /.git folder?

Comment: Ok i just moved the server directory to server2, commited and then moved server2 to server, so I think there was just some old information hanging around some were.

Comment: I see, you're right that cloned repositories don't redirect to the repo when you click on it in the Gitlab web interface